# Efficiency of Streams in scheme

Tags: performance, stream, scheme, lisp, racket

As far as I learned using streams in large programs are way more efficient than using normal lisp in DrRacket.So why not the default evaluation is lazy evaluation in DrRacket?I wrote and put a timer procedure which calculates the time the work needed to be complete and in every complex program lazy eval was a lot faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK using streams when you are doing something like sorting is a waste of cycles since you need to be finished with the sort in order to know the first element. If you have tasks that work like a sort so that you'll need to evaluate a whole set you'll end up using more time than without streams. The reason for that is that the whole stream system has a cost as well as benefits.

The benefits of streams are the fact that you can do calculations in parallel so that the program doesn't need to do a whole loop before processing the first element. If you have n layers of processing streams you'll benefit when your program quits and all the other layers hasn't served you the whole thing yet.

DrRacket is not a language but an IDE. Racket is both a language (`#!racket` as first line of source) and the name of the implementation that implements it.

Racket supports `#!lazy` which is a lazy version of Racket. Basically everything works just like streams do, everywhere. You'll have the same benefits and cost.

None of the mentioned languages are Scheme, but `#!racket` was based on and was a superset of `#!r5rs`. Since then you have `#!r6rs` and the new `#!r7rs`. None of the official Scheme reports are lazy. The reason is that its predecessor was eager and making it lazy would completely change the language and ruin all backwards compatibility.

The innovation of Scheme in 1975 was lexical closures. The creators made lazy evaluation by need in an later report (by implementing `delay` and `force`). Other languages, like Haskell, are built to be lazy from the ground and they have a more advanced compiler to constant fold and make its code snappy.